# STARTTLS vs SSL/TLS в Thunderbird

Tags: ssl, openssl

Всем привет!
Настраиваю тестовый почтовый сервер с postfix и courier в локальной сети.
Есть вопрос по поводу настройки SSL в почтовых протоколах smtp и imap.

При подключении к моему серверу по протоколу **STARTTLS** на  **143** порту всё работает.
Однако *Thunderbird* не подключается по **imap** на **993** порту по обычному **SSL/TLS**.
То есть, при добавлении нового почтового ящика в **Thunderbird** автоматически обнаруживается конфигурация для подключения по **IMAP** с использованием протокола **STARTTLS** к **143** порту.

Однако если в ручном режиме указать подключаться к 993 порту по SSL/TLS, то возникает совсем неинформативная ошибка: "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account".
При этом в mail логе пишет ошибку:
`mail imapd-ssl: couriertls: read: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca`

Самое обидное что проверка командой `'openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:993'` проходит и я могу подключится через консоль, а через Thunderbird - нет.

Как сконфигурировать **postfix** и **courier-imap-ssl** так чтобы можно было подключится с помощью **Thunderbird** по **SSL/TLS** к **993** порту?

Comment: 993-й обычно слушает imap-сервер (`grep 993 /etc/services`), т.е. *postfix* (не реализующий функциональность imap-сервера) не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: *Однако Thunderbird не подключается* — добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос больше подробностей по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема наконец таки решилась. Дело было в том, что при конфигурации *courier-imap-ssl* нужно было указать не просто самоподписанный сертификат, а сгенерить корневой сертификат и подписать им сертификат для *courier-imap-ssl*.
Лично мне помогла разобраться  [вот эта статья.](http://pro-ldap.ru/tr/zytrax/tech/ssl.html)